# How to move a block of content to the right of another block without moving it in the DOM

Tags: css

This might be pushing a bit what can be done with CSS (or show my total limitations). I have some HTML and CSS here:

http://jsbin.com/janujolofu/1/edit?html,css,output

that looks like this:

[image]

and I'd like the 12.50 value to look like this (ie moved to the right of `.jt-header` by `50px` or so):

[image]

Is this possible in CSS? How would I do this? Ideally, I would like the `.jt-price` to stay within `.jt-header` as this is the HTML, and not do some jQuery monkeying of moving it in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use position absolute, then use position relative on it's parent container to set a reference point:

```
.jt-item-price {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 70px;
}
.jt-row {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: impressive css-fu; have to wait a few minutes; might go to lunch

Answer (score 0):

display:table could be your friend:

```css
.jt-header {
  display:table;
}
.jt-item-price {
  display:table-cell;width:50%;
}
div {/* demo purpose */
  border:solid;
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='jt-container'>
  <div class='jt-row'>
    <div class='jt-circle'>
    </div>
    <div class='jt-header'>
      here is a header 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text
      <div class='jt-item-price'>
        12.50
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But your HTML struture should be rethought, use the less and then see how to style via CSS :)

Comment: display:flex/order, inline-block/direction and even float would easily do this on a clear structure :)

Comment: We are a bit stuck with this html structure unfortunately